# Send resolved async data via props from parent to child component - Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Nav :data="data" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// ... removed obvious imports for readability
@Component({
  components: {
    Nav: () => import('@/components/Nav.vue')
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {
  public nav: NavInterface = {}

  private getData(): Promise<any> {
    // ... this.$http - is an axios instance
    return this.$http
      .getData()
      .then((resp: any) => {
        this.data = resp.data.nav
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(nav, index) in data">{{ nav.id }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
// ... imports
export default class Nav extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: null }) public readonly data!: NavInterface

  private mounted(): void {
    console.log(this.data) // is undefined, because promise is not resolved yet - this is a problem
  }
}
</script>
```

There's a problem, when a promise resolved in a parent component, it won't be resolved in a child yet. Is it possible to load child component, only after my `getData()` promise is successfully resolved, because my child component has no sense without a data from a parent.

Of course, i can use a watcher in a child component, then, i'll get correct data from a promise, but it seems hacky for me:

```
@Watch('data')
private onPropChange(val: any) {
  console.log(val) // i get the correct data
}
```

I prefer to conditionally render my child component, only after promise is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shows an example approach. You'll need to vary this based on your actual requirements:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Nav v-if="isVisible" :items="navItems" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { navItems: [] };
  },
  computed: {
    isVisible() {
      return this.navItems.length > 0;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    return this.$http.getData().then(resp => {
      this.data.navItems = resp;
    });
  },
};
```

**Note:** I'm using the length of the `navItems` array to determine if it's visible. You may want to use a separate variable (e.g. `isLoaded`) to determine if the `Nav` should be rendered when there are no items or if there was an error.

Comment: I've tried that too, but in my case `navItems` was an empty object, so it gave me `true` all the time... I just used `Object.keys(navItems).length` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to your parent component an if statement:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Nav v-if="loaded" :data="data" />
  </div>
</template>
```

and in the function:

```
return this.$http
      .getData()
      .then((resp: any) => {
        this.data = resp.data.nav
        this.loaded = true
      })
```

OR if data.nav is null o doesn't exist after you fill the data

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <Nav v-if="data.nav" :data="data" />
      </div>
    </template>
```